# date format time ago

Tags: php

I'm still a beginner to PHP, but I need help with something. I got a date format for comments, and I'm trying to insert a "time ago" format. And I'm having trouble with it. This is the code:

```
<?php
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$comment = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['comment']);
$submit = $_POST['submit'];
$date = date("M jS Y | g:i a T");
$ip = "".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."";

if($submit)
{
if($name&&$comment)
{

$query=mysql_query("

INSERT INTO comment (id, articleid, name, comment, date, ip) VALUES ('','".  mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']) ."','$name','$comment','$date','$ip')

");
header("Location: " . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']) . "");

}
else
{
    echo "<div class='red'>You must fill in all fields!</div>";
}
```

}
?>

Here's the output:

```
<div class="article-body">
<div class="user"><b><?php echo $row['name'] ?></b> <span>says:</span></div> 
<div class="comments">
<?php echo $row['comment'] ?> <br /><p></p>

<p style="font-size:12px;">Posted on <b><?php echo $row['date'] ?></b></p>
</div>
</div>
```

I tried fiddling with a couple codes by using Google, but none successful, as I'm a noob. Haha.

Any tuts on this?

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you ever escape something for MySQL before using it in a `Location:` header?  That makes no sense.  Also, you have a nice XSS vulnerability if you don't wrap variable data with `htmlspecialchars()` when using it within the context of HTML/XHTML.

Comment: "I'm still a beginner to PHP" 

That said, it's a common beginner/inexperienced person's mistake to escape everything.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: I don't think anywhere on the title did it say "Need help with people pointing out my flaws in code", now if it did, then I'd take your comments into consideration... Good Game.

Comment: What is your mysql data type for `date`?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your MySQL Table Schema/Data Type, my guess would be that your `date` data is an invalid `date` value. (I assume that your `date` column is not `TEXT` or `VARCHAR`)

```
$date = date("M jS Y | g:i a T");
```

You can add `or die(mysql_error)` to you query to verify this-

```
$query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO comment (id, articleid, name, comment, date, ip) VALUES ('','".  mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']) ."','$name','$comment','$date','$ip')") or die(mysql_error);
```

According to the manual - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/datetime.html your data types for date are `date`,`datetime`, and `timestamp`.

```
date => 'YYYY-MM-DD' => set in php using date("Y-m-d");
datetime => 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' => set in php using date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
timestamp => 0000000000 => set in php using strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
```

Comment: I'm simply trying to add where it'll show the last post minutes/hours/days/months ago..

Comment: So what are you having issues with? Are you getting any error messages? If no error messages appear add `ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the top of you php script.